# accessing personal account data using graph URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I used graph API to extract users data for my project. I extracted based on the username of some popular companies. I am just curious about extracting data of personal user contents based on their username. Like all the posts and comments my friends posted recently. Is it legal or frowned upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get data of users who authorized your App. Getting the posts needs the `user_posts` permission, for example. There is no legal way to get posts or any data without authorization. There is no way to get data of friends without their permission/authorization either.